# How to know current process count and which process forks most processes?

Tags: linux, shell, process

```
fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

I'm investigating which process causees this problem and wondering how this mechanism works.

```
#!/bin/bash
#test.sh
for i in `seq 1 13000`; do
        echo $i
        sleep 60&
done
```

After I run this script(./test.sh), the messages are shown in below.

```
...
12265
12266
12267
12268
./test.sh: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
./test.sh: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
./test.sh: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
./test.sh: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
./test.sh: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

`ps -elf |wc` is about 133xx lines. `ulimit -u` is 1030977.

Does `fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable` shows due to process count reach 1030977? If true, how do I know current count and how to know which process forks most processes?

Answer (score 2):

Increase the value of "nproc" parameter for user or all user's in /etc/security/limits.conf

Example :

```
@student        hard    nproc           2048
```

Check: nproc value can be increased as per need.
Here template is :

```
    <domain>        <type>  <item>  <value>
    "@student" -- Replace it with user for which limit has to be applied. For root user, username is "root"
    "hard" for enforcing hard limits
    "nproc" for max number of processes
    Last column is value.
```

To find which process is forking most process, use the command "pstree". In order to determine count use the following method.

```
$ps | gawk '{count[$NF]++}END{for(j in count) print ""count[j]":",j}'|sort -rn|head -n 5
```

Example :

```
#ps | gawk '{count[$NF]++}END{for(j in count) print ""count[j]":",j}'|sort -rn|head -n 5
3: bash
1: sudo
1: sort
1: ps
1: CMD
```

Comment: I tried running your script and it was hung at the limit 10138 due to current limits i have set. 
    $ps | gawk '{count[$NF]++}END{for(j in count) print ""count[j]":",j}'|sort |head -n 5


10138: sleep
1: bash
1: CMD
1: gawk
1: head